# If $G \le S_n$ then $G/Z(G) \hookrightarrow S_{n^2}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

**Claim :** If $G \le S_n$ then $G/Z(G) \hookrightarrow S_{n^2}$

$Z(G)$ means center of group $G$ and $\le $ used for subgroup, $ \hookrightarrow$ is used for embedding.

> Question : How to prove the above claim?

Reference : [Page no 24](http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~luks/northeasterncourse.pdf)

Comment: Yes...and? It is fact true that $\;S_n\hookrightarrow A_{n+2}\;$ , so that doesn't look specially surprising. Any ideas?

Comment: @ DonAntonio  Any reference for your claim

Comment: What does it mean for a quotient group of $S_n$ to be included in $S_{n^2}$? Why the use of $\hookrightarrow$? Do you mean it's isomorphic to some subgroup?

Comment: @compu - yes but what is the inclusion map? I don't see any natural meaning for it in this context.

Comment: @compu: In this context, you don't mean an "inclusion map". What you mean is an "embedding", i.e., an injective homomorphism.

Comment: @quasi thanks for correction

Comment: Welp that's what I suggested. I downvoted because the inclusion map has no clear meaning here, and the fact that you couldn't explain made me suspicious this is a problem that someone else gave you. I would undo my downvote, except you've shown no working either so this isn't really a good question.

Comment: @compu - the PDF you linked gives this statement as a *corollary* of the previous theorem. Have you tried understanding that theorem?

Comment: yes previous proposition I have understood

Comment: @compu - usually a corollary indicates that the result comes as a side effect from the previous proof. Have you understood the proof of the theorem? I'm unfamiliar with some of the terminology and notation used, so I can't help much.

Comment: @compu The claim isn't trivial...but **very** easy to prove. Try it...

Answer (score 4):

It follows from the proof of the proposition with $H=G$, so $C_G(H)=Z(G)$. We know that $G \le {\rm Sym}(\Omega)$ with $|\Omega| = n$. There is an induced action of $G$ on $\Omega \times \Omega$.

Let $\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\ldots,\Pi_r$ be the orbits of $Z(G)$ on $\Omega \times \Omega$. Then the induced action of $G/Z(G)$ on the set $\{\Pi_1,\ldots,\Pi_r\}$ is faithful, and $r \le n^2$.

Comment: Could you explain why the induced action of $G/Z(G)$ on $\{\Pi_1,\dotsc, \Pi_r\}$ is faithful? And wouldn't your argument go through if we let $G$ act on $\Omega$ instead of $\Omega\times\Omega$?

Comment: The fact that the action is faithful is stated on line 5 of the proof of the proposition in the paper (where it says $C_G(H) = \{ \ldots \}$), and you said that you had understood that proof. The argument would not work for the action of $G$ on $\Omega$ because the action would not necessarily be faithful in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Notice that I never claimed to have understood the proof of the proposition. Nor that I even read it. This answer could be so much clearer if it didn't rely on the knowledge of the linked paper, which might not be permanently available. In fact, I cannot access the paper right now.